# DIY - Countryman B3  wired for Senn g2...how to mod to xlr?

Tags: diy

Im trying to make the things I have work for a new purpose.  I want to try and take my 2 Countryman B3's which are already wired to work with Sennheiser G2 units and make an adapter cable that way I can plug them straight into my Zoom so that I can do some low profile stealth recording akin to how people use the DPA/eyeglass rigs.

Buying a set of DPA's is on the list for the future.  But by some miracle I am graduating soon and figured it would be great to sneak a couple of mics on my person to get some stereo BG recordings of a large arena graduation.  If all else fails I will run them through my g2 units and then into the recorder, but I am trying to avoid the rizz I get in the high frequency range with those units.

I do not want a permanent mod so I was thinking of rewiring them from the g2 plug to a mini XLR.  Then make mini XLR to XLR adapters and Mini XLR to 3.5mm plug, that way I can swap as I need.

Anyone have any suggestions or tips?